# Writing text on a sphere in unity

Tags: text, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am using unity software for making a word drop game in which letters will be craved on the surface of ball(sphere) will fall from above and the user have to join them to form a word just like bubble game but balls will contain words
The problem is that i do not know how to crave the letters on the surface of ball so that when they fall from above different letters dynamically form on those balls
i tried to use GUI text but as i am a beginner in making games and on unity software i don't know how to use it
can anyone tell me how to right a script for this problem??

Answer (score 3):

make materials or textures of alphabets 
and add it to sphere..use 2 alphabets in single texture
so that it will appear on other side of sphere....

Comment: I know it's been a while.. but what does "attach it to the sphere" actually mean?